# How to implement shared session store with fastify

Tags: session, graphql, apollo-server, session-state, fastify

I am using apollo server 4 + fastify with @mgcrea/fastify-session
as my session store and can't get data to be shared between multiple requests.
My cookie configuration looks like this.

```js
  app.register(fastifySession, {
    cookieName: "qid",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new RedisStore({
      client: new Redis({ enableAutoPipelining: true }),
    }),
    secret: "cats",
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 31536e7,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "lax",
      secure: "auto",
    },
  });
```

My resolver looks like this.

```js
  @Query(() => Int, { nullable: true })
  test(@Ctx() { req }: MyCtx): number {
    req.session.set("5", 2);
    return req.session.get("5") as number;
  }
```

The code directly above returns 2 as expected. But when I use multiple resolvers it doesn't share the data as I would like it.

```js
  @Query(() => Int, { nullable: true })
  test(@Ctx() { req }: MyCtx): number {
    req.session.set("5", 2);
    return req.session.get("5") as number;
  }
  @Query(() => Int, { nullable: true })
  test2(@Ctx() { req }: MyCtx): number {
    return req.session.get("5") as number;
  }
```

Even when I execute `test` first then `test2`. `test2` always returns null.

How can I remedy this?

I tried to use the `req.session.data` object to store data instead but that didn't solve the issue.